# How to set a UIWebView's base URL

Tags: iphone, url, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView where relative links fail to load properly, because the view was loaded from a data object after the html data has been locally manipulated, not direct from a URL. Now all the relative links on the page fail, because the UIWebView doesn't know what they're relative to.

For example:

```
<IMG SRC="img/foo.jpg">
```

wouldn't load because rather than looking to

```
http://theoriginalsite.com/img/foo.jpg
```

for the file, the UIWebView looks in

```
iphonefilesystem/thisapp/tempdir/img/foo.jpg
```

Is there a way to reset the UIWebView's base URL, so that these links will work? Am I stuck with adding another pass to the html data manipulation to rewrite all the relative URLs within?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's exactly what the baseURL parameter in the following UIWebView methods is for:

```
- (void)loadData:(NSData *)data MIMEType:(NSString *)MIMEType textEncodingName:(NSString *)encodingName baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
- (void)loadHTMLString:(NSString *)string baseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
```

Have a look at the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).